# Application bandwidth monitor

Tags: windows, display, bandwidth

Which is the best application bandwidth monitor for my windows machine?

Some programs lurking in the background seems to pull up all the bandwidth and constraints my browsing experience. Are there programs to figure out bandwidth usage and show me a graph like output?

I am looking for OSS/freeware

**Edit:** I am looking for something that segregates bandwidth usage executable-wise and not as a sum of all the usage

Comment: Duplicate? Or at least a usable answer? http://superuser.com/questions/50680/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-app-is-using-most-of-my-bandwidth-in-windows (NetLimiter)

Answer (score 13):

In Windows 7 (and apparently Server 2008 and maybe Vista?), use "Resource Monitor".  It's under Accessories > System Tools.  The network tab shows network usage by process.

On Windows 8, you can find the *Open Resource Monitor* option at the bottom of the Performance tab in Task Manager.

Comment: This is a very useful tool. It also shows disk IO per process and various other interesting metrics.

Answer (score 0):

**[AnVir Task Manager Free](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/AnVir-Task-Manager-Free.shtml)** allows you to monitor the bandwidth usage by process/application.

> Freeware process and startup manager.
>   Remove spyware and optimize
>   performance. Monitor and manage
>   processes, services, internet
>   connections, DLLs, drivers.
>   Descriptions for startup programs and
>   all Windows services. Alerts on new
>   startups.
>
> Icons in tray for CPU usage and disk
>   load. Quick access to last launched
>   programs in tray. Hide windows to
>   system tray.
>
> Automatically change process priority,
>   permanently block undesired processes.
>   Furthermore, comes with an attractive
>   user interface.
>
> Advanced startup manager allows you
>   to: · Get full list of applications
>   running automatically on Windows
>   startup including all hidden
>   applications. · Get all additional
>   information about startup
>   applications. · Disable/enable,
>   add/delete, edit startup entries. ·
>   Stop or run once again startup
>   application.
>
> Startup guard allows you to: · See
>   alert when any new application adds
>   itself to startup. · Forbid some
>   applications to be added to startup. ·
>   See alert when Internet Explorer home
>   page was changed.
>
> Process manager allows you to: · Get
>   full information about all processes:
>   CPU and memory usage, executable name
>   with full path, priority, work time,
>   user name. · Get executable file
>   properties, icon and version
>   information. · Stop many processes
>   with one click. · Change process
>   priorities.
>
> Tray icons allows you to: · Get
>   current information about CPU usage
>   including list of most active
>   programs. · Get current information
>   about HDD usage. Protection against
>   viruses includes: · Detection and
>   destruction of most propagated
>   viruses. · Virus database update. ·
>   Minimum usage of system resources.

*A portable version can be downloaded [here](http://www.anvir.com/download.htm).*