# How can I find out which program takes how much bandwidth in Windows 7? 

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to find out what app is using most of my bandwidth in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/50680/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-app-is-using-most-of-my-bandwidth-in-windows)

When I connect to the Internet in Windows 7 Home Premium a program is taking up all the bandwidth. I can't find which program is doing this. I have a new Windows installation with all my software installed.

I already checked Window Update and for antivirus updates but this is not the cause.

Is there any software that can tell me which program is using this bandwidth?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `Resource Monitor` from `Task Manager` in `Windows 7`?

Its in `Task Manager` **>** `Performance` **>** `Network` **>** `Network Activity`.