# Bandwidth/internet traffic of selective programm

Tags: windows, monitoring, bandwidth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to find out what app is using most of my bandwidth in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/50680/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-app-is-using-most-of-my-bandwidth-in-windows)

I've got trouble. Some programm eat my internet traffic, but I can't understand which of.
I have installed bandwidth soft: Networx, but it didn't show traffic for programms, it only shows me summary traffic.

Can somebody help? How I can check traffic of selective programm?

Thank you.