# An application to monitor/stop network connections?

Tags: internet, bandwidth

I'm on a limited connection and the problem is that whenever I connect to the internet with the cable, using a desktop widget I note that it starts to use internet even without opening anything! and it continues to use the internet all the time which finishes my limited connection..

Is there an app that can report to me which apps use the most bandwidth and block it?

Answer (score 0):

Just like [Rob](https://superuser.com/users/1029/rob) [said](https://superuser.com/a/8409/81403) use [FreeMeter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemeter/)

See the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/q/8404/81403) question.

OR you can use [network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en) instructions for use can be found [here](http://www.sysprobs.com/monitor-network-traffic-windows-7-microsoft-network-monitor-34).