# Why does Dropbox upload at only 1/10th of my internet upload speed?

Tags: speed, performance, dropbox, upload, transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it me, or is Dropbox really slow?](https://superuser.com/questions/267375/is-it-me-or-is-dropbox-really-slow)

I have just purchased 50g of storage and am transfering files to go roaming.
My internet speed shows as 860kb/sec on a speed test but I ma only getting a transfer rate to Dropbox of50 -80 kb/sec. That means I will take 19 days to process the files to Dropbox. I will be bback from holiday by then.
Does that sound right to you or have I done something wrong to get such dismal upload speeds?
I have delimeted both upload and download in settings.
Nothing else is running on the line.